# Entering Jannah without Judgement

Tags: jannah, day-of-judgement

How can someone be among the 70,000 people who enter Jannah without judgement?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

“Those people are those who do not treat themselves with Ruqya, nor do they believe in bad or good omen (from birds etc.) nor do they get themselves branded (Cauterized). but they put their trust (only) in their Lord “

Sahih bukhari Volume 7, Book 71, Number 606

Comment: This needs some elaboration and explanation as to why you've chosen this hadith (part) instead of [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/434) or [this](https://sunnah.com/urn/1344250) or [this](https://sunnah.com/muslim/1/428) or [this](https://sunnah.com/urn/726190) and many more.

Comment: Med1Saif, that is because it answers the question at hand, and I am not aware if there is any other hadith about this, but you sound like you do please enlighten me.

Answer (score 0):

Reference

Tell us Hassan bin Arafa, told us Ismail bin Ayyash, Muhammad ibn Ziyad Alolhana, said I heard the father Umaamah, say I heard the Messenger of Allah , peace be upon him says , "I promised my Lord to enter paradise of my seventy thousand does not account for them nor torment with every thousand Seventy thousand and three exhortations of his exhortations . "Abu Issa said this hadeeth is good for a stranger.